# JNA Structure inside a structure

Tags: java, pointers, structure, jna

I am quite new to JNA programming. I have a native code as below

```
int Data(int Number, aaa *Data, int* error);

typedef struct {
    uint8 Storage;
    LStr path;
    int32 chart;
    int32 strt;
    LStr val;
    int32 timedata;
    } aaa;

typedef struct {
    int32   cnt;    /*num of bytes that follow*/    
    uChar   str[1]; 
} LStrval, *LStrPtr, **LStr;
```

How can I call this native function from Java using JNA. I tried several options, but I am not getting the results. one of the options I tried is below.

the interface function

```
public int SetStorage_Data(int num,Storage_Data.ByReference data, Pointer error);

 public class Storage_Data extends Structure{
        public static class ByReference extends Storage_Data implements Structure.ByReference {}

        public byte storage;
        public Stringtype.ByReference savepath;
        public int chart;
        public int strt;
        public Stringtype.ByReference val;
        public int timedata;

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("storage", "savepath","chart",
                    "strt","val","timedata");
        }
    }



public class Stringtype extends Structure{
        public static class ByReference extends Stringtype implements Structure.ByReference {

            public ByReference(int buffersize) {
                super(buffersize);
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }}

        public int count;
        public byte[] str;

        public Stringtype(int buffersize) {
            str = new byte[buffersize];
            count = str.length;
            allocateMemory();
        }

        @Override
        protected List getFieldOrder() {
            return Arrays.asList("count", "str");
        }
    }
```

And the Java call

```
InjectionAnalyzerInterfaces.Storage_Data.ByReference storagedata = new InjectionAnalyzerInterfaces.Storage_Data.ByReference();

 int len= string.length;
 InjectionAnalyzerInterfaces.Stringtype.ByReference savepath = new InjectionAnalyzerInterfaces.Stringtype.ByReference(len);

            byte[] stringbyte = string.getBytes();
            System.arraycopy(stringbyte, 0, savepath.str, 0, bytes);
            storagedata.savepath = savepath;
            storagedata.chart = 1;
            storagedata.strt =1;
            String temp= "all";
            byte[] strtbyte = temp.getBytes();
            int dd = strtbyte.length;
            InjectionAnalyzerInterfaces.Stringtype.ByReference stra = new InjectionAnalyzerInterfaces.Stringtype.ByReference(dd);
            System.arraycopy(strtbyte, 0,  stra.str,0, dd);
            storagedata.strt = stra;


            storagedata.tdata = 0;

            Pointer error = new Memory(5);

            int status1 =  lib.Set_Config_Storage_Data(deviceNumber, storagedata, error);
```

Please do help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: I'd recommend you start with using `Pointer` for those fields, then use various `Pointer` access methods to extract and format the data the way you want.  Once you understand the levels of dereferencing, you can figure out the most sensible way to map it.  You've got a fundamental problem, though, in that your field is `struct**`, which JNA isn't going to recognize, so all the calls to `Structure.read/write` are entirely up to you to perform.

Comment: @technomage  is it better to use `Pointer.getPointer(0)` or `PointerByReference.getValue()` ?

Comment: You should only use `PointerByReference` if you're passing the address of a pointer as a parameter to something.  If you've just got `void**` as a field somewhere, use `Pointer`.

Answer (score 1):

In defining your `LStrVal`, you need to initialize the primitive array field so that JNA knows how much memory to allocate (at least to start with):

```
public byte str = new byte[1];
```

You need to override `Structure.read()` to do the right thing, and provide a `Pointer`-based constructor to read after initializing from native memory:

```
public void read() {
    count = (int)readField("count");
    str = new byte[count];
    super.read();
}

public LStr(Pointer p) {
    super(p);
    read();
}
```

Finally, your containing struct has `struct**` fields (no idea why), which you'll have to map to `Pointer`, and provide a convenience function to actually convert to your desired structure:

```
public Pointer savepath;
public LStr getSavepath() {
    return savepath != null ? new LStr(savepath.getPointer(0)) : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

You need to declare the inner structure (`LStrVal`) as its own structure class.  It looks like you've done that with your `Stringtype` structure but you need to change a few things there:

- Get rid of the constructor with the int arg. Your C structure specifies the size of the `byte[]` array as 1, just use that constant.
- You need a no-arg constructor that calls `super()`
- You need a constructor with a Pointer arg p that calls `super(p)`
- You don't need the `ByReference` parts

Then the outer structure you should use a `PointerByReference` type for those structure pointers, and then in your main code, use `new Stringtype(pbr.getValue())` to convert the pointer into the necessary class.

Alternately, as @technomage suggests, you could use a Pointer type, and then instead of `getValue()` you'd use `getPointer(0)`.   Bottom line is that you need a pointer (to a pointer) as your instance variable.

Comment: `LStr` has type `struct**`, which does _not_ map onto `Structure.ByReference` (that'd be `struct*`, within the context of a struct field).

Comment: Just reread and noticed that and edited my answer appropriately.